# I want to convert array to object in java script like[ ["key1","ans1"],["key2","ans2"] ]=> {key1:"ans1",key2:"ans2"}

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, converters

I want to convert array to object in javascript like
`[["key1","ans1"],["key2","ans2"]]` => `{key1:"ans1",key2:"ans2"}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go;

```js
    let res = {}
    let arr = [["key1","ans1"],["key2","ans2"]]
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        res[arr[i][0]] = arr[i][1]
    }

    console.log(res)
```

please comment if you need explanation.

Comment: Can you please explain what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: Your answer is correct for previous question. Could you please edit it for updated question.

Comment: Edited my answer and works fine with your new question.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working. Again thankyou....

Comment: please leave an upvote also. Thanks!

Comment: also comment if you need explanation